# Create QuickStart Package for Wordpress just like in Joomla

Tags: themes, installation

I need a simple help that I am unable find a good documentation for creating a quickstart package for Wordpress, same like we already have in Joomla. I have very much noob to wordpress dev. I recently built a wordpress website in which I have ported an HTML theme into wordpress theme. Now, all devs are finished, website is fine in my local machine, I just need to create a quickstart/ready-to-work package of this wordpress file, what I mean is, once install this package into live server/anywhere, it should be like a normal wordpress install but it will have all contents and theme that I have created.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the [latest version](http://wordpress.org/latest.zip) of WordPress;
2. Copy your theme into `wp-content/themes/` folder;
3. Add `define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'yourthemename' );` at the beginning of **wp-config-sample.php** file;
4. Archive all files;
5. Install it on your servers.